# What feature need to be enabled for entities filtering on Jhipster?

Tags: jhipster

What those words "When this feature is enabled" on this documentation http://www.jhipster.tech/entities-filtering/ refer to ?

My jdl file is OK (thanks for the recent implemenattion : https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6286 )

Command `jhipster import-jdl my_jdl_file.jdl` work well.

But, I don't know what refer to "this feature" so it doesn't work (with swagger or postman).

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to enable filtering in JDL you have to:

- Use the filter keyword
- Your entities must use a service class or implementation.

The sample JDL below will create the filter classes for entity A:

```
entity A
entity B
filter * except B
service * with serviceClass
```

If you generate your entities through the prompts, make sure to enable Service Class and Filtering options.

As an example with a Foo entity, in your `foo.component.ts`, you can add keys to the query object to filter on those fields:

```
this.fooService.query({ 'id.equals': 953 })
```

[JDL Docs](http://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/)

[Entity Filtering Docs](http://www.jhipster.tech/entities-filtering/)

Comment: Hi Ckram,

Yes it is what I did on JDL file. But it is not working on swagger and I am pretty sure I missed something to enable filter entities (cf : http://www.jhipster.tech/entities-filtering/#implementation )

Comment: Can you check if in your .jhipster directory the entities you want to filter have "jpaMetamodelFiltering": true ?

Comment: @DamDam As mentioned at the bottom of the Filtering docs, you also need to enable a service class or service implementation for filtering to work.  I have updated this answer to reflect that (edit is pending)

Comment: Yes I  forgot that the service is required to have filtering thanks

Comment: Thanks @JonRuddell for that `service * with serviceClass`

Comment: Hi guys,
Using JHipster 4.14.3 but there's no file `.jhispter`

Comment: Googling it did not help, nor asking a friend so I kept thinking as a JHipster conceptor until I found that adding the `jpaMetamodelFiltering` entry into `.yo-rc.json` worked when I re-generated my entities.

Comment: @SalathielGenèse I updated the answer to show how to use it.  Adding `jpaMetamodelFiltering` to `.yo-rc.json` is not supported and won't work in all cases, this property is configured individually for entities

Comment: @JonRuddell , ty for paying attention but (1) I'm not sure what you mean by **is not supported**, (2) in what specific condition does it not working, (3) what's the **official way** to support it for all entities? given that we mostly edit only the JDL (4) as the answer still not mention where to put that `jpaMetamodelFiltering` config.

Comment: I afterward asked at Gitter and discovered the `id.equals` syntax but `grandEntity.entity.id.equals` seem not to work. Any idea ? ty

Comment: `jpaMetamodelFiltering` is enabled by the JDL `filter * except B` which is present in the answer (also requires the `service` line as explained).  Adding it to `.yo-rc.json` is not correct, it's an entity option, not an app option. Where did you get `grandEntity.entity.id.equals` from?  If you have an unrelated question you should ask a separate question.